Connect custom online prediction endpoint in vertex AI with langchain
Deployed model(meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3-8B) in vertexAI from huggingface.
Need to connect the endpoint in langchain and get the prediction.

Hi @Jacob, Could you elaborate and provide more details on the issue, like what steps you followed or any documentation and clarify your expectation.
